# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assingnment

Tags: python

I am currently trying to make a Russian Roulette Program. The goal is to randomly select a integer in a range of 6, then determine if the randomly chosen number is assigned as death or safe.

My current code is this:

```
import random

deaths = 0
alive = 0

def roulette():
    bullet = random.randint(1,6)
    if bullet == 1:
        bullet =("safe")
    elif bullet == 2:
        bullet =("safe")
    elif bullet == 3:
        bullet =("safe")
    elif bullet == 4:
        bullet =("safe")
    elif bullet == 5:
        bullet =("safe")
    elif bullet == 6:
        bullet =("death")
    
    print(bullet)

    if bullet == ("death"):
        deaths+=1

    if bullet == ("safe"):
        alive+=1

    print(death, alive)


roulette()
```

The produced error code:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'alive' referenced before assignment
```

I tried to solve it with making the 'alive' variable global before the line where the function was written instead of local with:

```
global alive
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `deaths+=1`:  The variable `deaths` is out of scope from within the `roulette()` function.  The same is true for `alive`.  If you want to use those variables inside the function you need to pass them in as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `global` keyword inside the function `roulette` to mark the variable as global within the scope of the function.

```
import random

deaths = 0
alive = 0

def roulette():
    global alive, deaths

    bullet = random.randint(1,6)
    if bullet == 1:
        bullet =("safe")
    elif bullet == 2:
        bullet =("safe")
    elif bullet == 3:
        bullet =("safe")
    elif bullet == 4:
        bullet =("safe")
    elif bullet == 5:
        bullet =("safe")
    elif bullet == 6:
        bullet =("death")

    print(bullet)

    if bullet == ("death"):
        deaths+=1

    if bullet == ("safe"):
        alive+=1

    print(deaths, alive)


roulette()
```

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning: OP will also have a minor problem with vairable names `death` vs `deaths`

Answer (score 0):

Pass as an argument; return the changed values; assign the return values

```
death = 0
alive = 0

def roulette(death,alive):
    ...
    if bullet == ("death"):
        deaths+=1

    if bullet == ("safe"):
        alive+=1

    return (death, alive)

death,alive = roulette(death,alive)
```

Answer (score 0):

for this to run as is bring the global definition into the method:

```
def roulette():
    global alive, deaths
```

Doing things with `global` has a bit of a smell. I would recommend using a class with alive and deaths as object vars instead